# PHP radom output from key value array

Tags: php, arrays, random

How can I get the follow thing done.

The follow array I have:

```
array(2) { [0] => array(3) {
["id"] => string(1) "5"
["avatar"] => string(15) "4e0d886ee9ed3_n"
["username"] => string(5) "testuser1"}
[1] => array(3) {
["id"] => string(1) "1"
["avatar"] => string(15) "4e25bc58b6789_w"
["username"] => string(6) "testuser2"
}
}
```

I want to create a array with just one user in it, but it has to be random. It can be like
user with id=5, id=1 or a hole other user (when there are more users).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try, something like:

```
 $rand = array_rand($your_array);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$rand_user = array_rand($your_array);
```

[PHP Manual: array_rand](http://php.net/array_rand)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_rand()`.

```
$randomKey = array_rand($yourArray);
$randomUserId = $yourArray[$randomKey]['id'];
```

Simple.

Comment: Tank you very much, I was stuck in the situation of array_rand and I didn't get what i wanted. Thanks!